# How to plot 2 subplots from different functions in the same window(figure)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

for specific reasons I have two functions, each of them creates a plot in two different windows. Is it possible to unify this two plots in one window, without unifying the functions?
thanks!

edit: I have 2 involved functions and a database: function 1 in file1.py plots a 2d-line plot:

```
plt.figure("TEST12") 
ax=plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(array[:,10])
```

In file2.py theres my other function, which plots a filled contour:

```
plt.figure("TEST13")
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.contourf(x,y,data)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

If I use `plt.show`as usual, the result are 2 different windows.

Comment: It depends :-) Edit the post with at least the coding language and the plotting library you're using

Comment: @flebool, added a few details :)

Comment: Be more specific. What does "create a plot/subplot" mean? are you talking about figure or axis objects? what are the definitions of the 2 functions? Please post some code and your progress so far http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @flebool ok.. what you think about my second edit? :D

Comment: Are they even running in the same python process?  If so, just pass the figure (or better, axes) object into the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re-factor your function to take an `Axes` object to draw to as an argument:

```
def fun1(ax):
    ax.plot(range(5))

def fun2(ax):
    ax.plot(range(5)[::-1])


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

fun1(ax)
fun2(ax)

plt.draw()
```